# multi line text for input

Tags: php, html

How can I make multi line text input ?
My code outputs only the first word of any input
For example if I type in "Hello world" it will only print "Hello"
My goal is to display multi line text.
My current code is:

```
echo "<td><input type=text name=opis value=".$row['opis']." </td>";
```

I know  is the correct tag , but i can't incorporate that into my code.
My code outputs only the first word of any input
For example if I type in "Hello world" it will only print "Hello"

Comment: try to mark value as text, eg: `echo "<td><input type=text name=opis value='".$row['opis']."' </td>";`

Comment: For one thing, you have an HTML syntax error. It's missing the closing `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Always **wrap** you attributes values in quotes. Suppose your `$row['opis']` has value "some value here", so in rendered html it will be:

```
<td><input type=text name=opis value=some value here /></td>
```

So do you think browser will understand that "some value here" is data of `value` attribute and **not** a list of some other attributes?

So, use quotes with attributes' values, **always**:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="opis" value="' . $row['opis'] . '" /></td>';
```

As you can see I've changed quotes and also **closed** input tag ( `/>`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you mean with a multi line text input, but in HTML that would be the `textarea` element.

You can use it and specify how much rows do you want it to show initially. It will normally be bigger than an `input[type='text']`.

Your code would be something like this:

```php
echo '<td><textarea name="opis" rows="5">'.$row['opis'].'</textarea></td>';
```

Also, if you want to echo something that requires the use of `"` you can just do:

```php
echo '<td class="test">'.$content.'</td>';
// or in its case the other way around
echo "<td class='test'>".$content."</td>";
```

Here's an example of the difference between the two elements:

```html
<input type="text" value='Hello&#13;&#10;World&#13;&#10;!&#13;&#10;I&#13;&#10;Am&#13;&#10;Here'>
<br><br>
<textarea rows="5">Hello&#13;&#10;World&#13;&#10;!&#13;&#10;I&#13;&#10;Am&#13;&#10;Here</textarea>
```